# Vertically Align placeholder text in input

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

I have an issue with this placeholder text input, I was trying to align the center of this placeholder text vertically, I have used absolute position for this issue it's worked fine but not on older safari versions.

PS: I have used tailwind CSS for stylings.

[image]

[here's the tailwind-play code link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YwYz74mwCe?size=288x720)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi https://play.tailwindcss.com/YwYz74mwCe?size=288x720

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution myself for the above problem, here's the code

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
}

#text-input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#input-label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#input-label,
#text-input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: text;

}

#text-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ #input-label {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input placeholder=" " id="text-input" />
  <label for="text-input" id="input-label">
    Find anything for your next garment project
  </label>
</div>
```